# How to retrieve data from firestore into tabbar tabs? in flutter firebase dynamic firestore tabbar

Tags: android, ios, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, tabbar

I am new to flutter and having problem to make dynamic tabbar tabview for video category screen same like youtube scrollable tabbar for speciic video category
i tried lot of example not having proper solution to make tab bar tabs dynamically from firebase firestore data is there any way? please explain with code

i have tried with model , streambuilder, futurebuilder , statically defining tabs in tabbars tab property

like:

```
TabBar(
              controller: _tabController,
              indicatorWeight: 4,
              indicatorColor: ColorTheme.Blue,
              isScrollable: true,
              tabs: [
                Tab(child: Text('All', style: TextStyle(color: ColorTheme.Blue, fontSize: 20))),
                Tab(child: Text('Narrative', style: TextStyle(color: ColorTheme.Blue, fontSize: 20))),
                Tab(child: Text('Branded Content', style: TextStyle(color: ColorTheme.Blue, fontSize: 20))),
                Tab(child: Text('Animation', style: TextStyle(color: ColorTheme.Blue, fontSize: 20))),
                Tab(child: Text('Sports', style: TextStyle(color: ColorTheme.Blue, fontSize: 20))),
                Tab(child: Text('Ads & Commercials', style: TextStyle(color: ColorTheme.Blue, fontSize: 20))),
                Tab(child: Text('Travel', style: TextStyle(color: ColorTheme.Blue, fontSize: 20))),
                Tab(child: Text('Documentry', style: TextStyle(color: ColorTheme.Blue, fontSize: 20))),
                Tab(child: Text('Music', style: TextStyle(color: ColorTheme.Blue, fontSize: 20))),
                Tab(child: Text('Comedy', style: TextStyle(color: ColorTheme.Blue, fontSize: 20))),
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic?. do you want the tabbar to be scrollable?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Saad i just want to fetch categories title from firestore into tabbar tabs

Answer (score 0):

Setting isScrollable to true makes the TabBar scrollable horizontally.

[image]

**Fullcode**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const TabControllerExampleApp());

class TabControllerExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const TabControllerExampleApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyTabbedPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyTabbedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTabbedPage({super.key});
  @override
  State<MyTabbedPage> createState() => _MyTabbedPageState();
}

class _MyTabbedPageState extends State<MyTabbedPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  static const List<Tab> myTabs = <Tab>[
    Tab(text: 'All'),
    Tab(text: 'Narrative'),
    Tab(text: 'Branded Content'),
    Tab(text: 'Animation'),
    Tab(text: 'Sports'),
    Tab(text: 'Ads & Commercials'),
    Tab(text: 'Travel'),
    Tab(text: 'Documentry'),
    Tab(text: 'Music'),
    Tab(text: 'Comedy'),
  ];

  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: myTabs.length);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          isScrollable: true,
          controller: _tabController,
          tabs: myTabs,
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: myTabs.map((Tab tab) {
          final String label = tab.text!.toLowerCase();
          return Center(
            child: Text(
              label,
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 36),
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Please refer here.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabController-class.html)

Comment: could you give me example with firebase firestore and tabbar tabs and tabview dynamically